# Dynamically change input value depending on select list item in ASP.NET Core 3 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, dropdown

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app with Razor Pages. I have the following classes (simplified):

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public decimal PointsPerUnit { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityLog
{
    public int ActivityLogId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public int Units { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPoints { get; set; }

    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

There is a foreign key between the two SQL tables, on the field ActivityId.

And here is my Razor page (simplified):

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ActivityLog.ActivityId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select id="activityId" asp-for="ActivityLog.ActivityId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ActivityId">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ActivityLog.Units" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="ActivityLog.Units" class="form-control" id="units" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ActivityLog.Units" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ActivityLog.TotalPoints" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="ActivityLog.TotalPoints" class="form-control" readonly="@true" value="" id="totalPoints" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ActivityLog.TotalPoints" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

@foreach (var item in Model.Activities)
{
    <input id="activity-@item.ActivityId" type="hidden" value="@item.PointsPerUnit" />
}
```

I also have a Razor page to create new "ActivityLog". On that page I have a select list (dropdown) populated with a List in which the Value is the ActivityId and the Text is the ActivityName.

What I need to do is to dynamically calculate the field TotalPoints when the user selects an Activity from the select list and inputs a value in the Units field (TotalPoints = PointsPerUnit * Units).

The problem is I can't find a way to access the PointsPerUnit for the selected Activity inside the Razor page and dynamically set the value of the TotalPoints field.

I managed to do it using JavaScript, but I guess there is a better and cleaner approach. Here is the code that worked for me:

(external JS file):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#activityId", calculateTotalPoints);
    $(document).on("change", "#units", calculateTotalPoints);

    function calculateTotalPoints() {
        var units = $("#units").val();
        var pointsPerUnit = $("#activity-" + $("#activityId").val()).val();

        if (units != "" && pointsPerUnit != "") {
            var totalPoints = units * pointsPerUnit;
            console.log("totalPoints: " + totalPoints);
            $("#totalPoints").val(totalPoints);
        }
        else {
            $("#totalPoints").val("");
        }
    }
});
```

I still have only 2 rows in the Activity table, but if it grows it would mean creating many hidden inputs on the page. Is there a way to do it without client-side code?

Thanks.

Comment: I would make an API with a function that calculates the value and call this function from javascript using fetch(), so you keep all your business logic in server code.

Answer (score 0):

> I still have only 2 rows in the Activity table, but if it grows it would mean creating many hidden inputs on the page. Is there a way to do it without client-side code?

1.Comment out the following code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Activities)
{
  <input id="activity-@item.ActivityId" type="hidden" value="@item.PointsPerUnit" />
}
```

2.Change the  `calculateTotalPoints` function:

```
function calculateTotalPoints() {
    var units = $("#units").val();
    var activityId = $("#activityId").val();
    var pointsPerUnit;
    var list =@Json.Serialize(Model.Activities);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length;i++){
        if (activityId == list[i].activityId) {
            pointsPerUnit = list[i].pointsPerUnit;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (units != "" && pointsPerUnit != "") {
        var totalPoints = units * pointsPerUnit;
        console.log("totalPoints: " + totalPoints);
        $("#totalPoints").val(totalPoints);
    }
    else {
        $("#totalPoints").val("");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On the line with "@Json.Serialize(Model.Activities)" I get a blue squiggly line and a warning message that says "(JS) Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.".
I was kind of hoping there was a way to access the other columns of the collection, not only the ones assigned to "Id" and "Value" in the selected item on the dropdown list.

Comment: @GeorgiYanakiev ,if you need the other column value of the Model.Activties,you can use list[i].xxx.

Comment: I know I can use the index, but the thing is I don't know which item is the user going to select. I want something like `<input value="@list[ActivityId.SelectedItem].PointsPerUnit" />`

Comment: Try to change the `for` loop code in javascript with `var pointsPerUnit = list.filter(activity => activity.activityId == activityId)[0].pointsPerUnit;`

Comment: Thank you @XueliChen I already had working code with JavaScript, my question was whether it's possible or not to do it without client-side code (JavaScript).